# Was Lord Bowler an American Cavalry Soldier before he became a bounty hunter?

Tags: character, brisco-county-jr

I'm watching [The Adventures of Brisco County Jr.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105932/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (currently on S01E07) and I've noticed that his pants have a yellow stripe down them. According to what I know, [American calvary soldiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalry_in_the_American_Civil_War) during and after the Civil War wore pants with a yellow stripe down them exactly like Lord Bowler's. I also know  there were [African American cavalry soldiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10th_Cavalry_Regiment_%28United_States%29) during the time period, so this seems very plausible to me, but I couldn't find anything online nor have I seen anything during the series to confirm this. Any evidence other than his pants to support this? I imagine there are plenty of other explanations to explain  this besides him behing a former cavalry soldier.

Here's a snap shot revealing the yellow stripe on his pants.

[image: Lord Bowler]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, Lord Bowler (his real name is [*James Lonefeather*](http://paul.rutgers.edu/%7Ecwm/Brisco-County-Jr/Bowler.html))

> was **First Sergeant in the US *10th Cavalry***. The Cavalry trousers he wears are an artifact of his time in the Army.
>
> During his time in the Army, he met the love of his life, *Lenore Raymond*, but couldn't do anything about it because she was married to a Lieutenant.

(This information is revealed in [**Episode 18: "Hard Rock"**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0505802/))

---

Additional sources:

- [The Ultimate Adventures of Brisco County, Jr. Guidebook](http://theoasis.com/brisco/encyclopedia/encyclopedia.php#Bowler)
- [Blacks In The Old West](http://veethemonsoon.wordpress.com/2004/06/14/blacks-in-the-old-west-new-york/)

Comment: Guess I should have waited until I completed the series, but it was just bugging me more and more as each episode went on.